# Tektronix 2236 Help

Tags: oscilloscope

[image]

Hi,

My oscilloscope only displays a dot or vertical line and does not draw across the whole screen. I was wondering if anyone knew if a setting was wrong or what I can do to get it to display a wave horizontally instead of just a vertical line.

Thanks

Comment: Select auto triggering, turn the holdoff down to "Norm", and exercise all the timebase switches vigorously to try to clean them. Does the X Position control (above the timebase knob) move the  spot all the way across the screen? If none of these help, you are probably looking at a repair.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you need to press in the P-P Auto button. The CRO is waiting for a trigger.

To understand your controls you need the manual, there is a copy [here](http://w140.com/Tektronix-2236-Oscilloscope-service-1986-WW.pdf), and read section 2-5.

Connect your probe to the probe calibration pin (read section 2-2) and you'll get a square wave to help you test timebase, vertical and trigger controls.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Power regulator for ~ flyback H sweep ~150~250V possible range is dead.

Get a service manual and troubleshoot H sweep.

Search google videos. They have solutions.

“Tektronix 2236 h sweep repair”

Answer (score 0):

The display seems to be saying “No A trigger”. If true, the trace is waiting for that trigger. Make sure it’s set for auto. Turn down your he hold off. If that’s still showing, perhaps those controls have failed.